# Passing same PDO object to different classes

Tags: php, pdo

I have classes like this:

classPages.php

```
class pages {

    private $dbh;

    function __construct($dbh) { 
        $this->dbh = $dbh;
    }
    //...
}
```

classNews.php

```
class news {

    private $dbh;

    function __construct($dbh) { 
        $this->dbh = $dbh;
    }
    //...
}
```

classMod.php

```
class mod {

    private $dbh;

    function __construct($dbh) { 
        $this->dbh = $dbh;
    }
    //...
}
```

And in index page:

```
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

require 'classPages.php';
require 'classNews.php';
require 'classMod.php';

$pages = new pages($dbh);
$news = new news($dbh);
$mod = new mod($dbh);

//use above objects where needed
```

So i create single PDO object. Then pass it to the constructors of each classes. Then i use these objects and calls it's member functions which does fetching and insertion of data using this pdo object passed to constructor.

Is it correct way? Or any conflicts directly/indirectly happen?

Comment: Yes this is a great design, it's called dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way.  You don't create a different DB connection each time, which is optimal (not sure that new PDO instances do that anyway, but you can at least be sure).

When you prepare statements in PDO, it creates a separate instance so there is no worry of conflict there.  The only possible problem is if you change some of the attributes of the PDO instance in one class and depend on working with different attributes in another (but this is highly unlikely).

One of the goals of Object Oriented Programming is to reuse resources which is exactly what this does.